# Android FileNotFoundException during FileTransfer upload

Tags: android, cordova, filenotfoundexception

preface: I have seen a couple other similar posts but no successful answers. That's why I'm posting this question. Sorry for the duplicate post, but the site says to only respond with answers. =)

I'm new to Android development but have been doing web development for over a decade.

I am just trying to get the PhoneGap 2.1 FileTransfer 'full example' working. Nothing too extreme, right?

MYURL in the error log below reflects my actual URL and yes it does exist. For some reason the emulator can not access this site. Why not? Android 4.1.2

The server file I'm transferring to doesn't actually do anything at the moment, so it can't be a server side error. The file is blank. Once I know the emulator sending and I get a good response I'll do my server side file upload.

BTW I'm using Cold Fusion server side -- but I doubt that makes a difference.

I've tried editing Config.xml with the following lines:

```
<access origin="*"/>
<access origin=".*"/>
<access origin="MYURL"/>
```

Thanks for your help. You resolve this issue I can buy you a coffee or beer!

Error Log:

```
10-20 19:22:51.400: E/FileTransfer(726): java.io.FileNotFoundException: MYURL
10-20 19:22:51.400: E/FileTransfer(726): java.io.FileNotFoundException: MYURL
10-20 19:22:51.400: E/FileTransfer(726):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
10-20 19:22:51.400: E/FileTransfer(726):    at org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer.upload(FileTransfer.java:302)
10-20 19:22:51.400: E/FileTransfer(726):    at org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer.execute(FileTransfer.java:86)
10-20 19:22:51.400: E/FileTransfer(726):    at org.apache.cordova.api.PluginManager$1.run(PluginManager.java:231)
10-20 19:22:51.400: E/FileTransfer(726):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-20 19:22:51.410: E/FileTransfer(726): {"target":"MYURL","source":"content:\/\/media\/external\/images\/media\/12","http_status":500,"code":3}
10-20 19:22:51.410: E/FileTransfer(726): java.io.IOException: Received error from server
10-20 19:22:51.410: E/FileTransfer(726):    at org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer.upload(FileTransfer.java:305)
10-20 19:22:51.410: E/FileTransfer(726):    at org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer.execute(FileTransfer.java:86)
10-20 19:22:51.410: E/FileTransfer(726):    at org.apache.cordova.api.PluginManager$1.run(PluginManager.java:231)
10-20 19:22:51.410: E/FileTransfer(726):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: FIXED! Make sure you don't have any underlying Application.cfm or Application.cfc code going on that might throw an error when the object is being transferred. I moved the script into it's own folder with an empty Application.cfm and now it works.

Comment: please write your own comment as an answer and mark it as accepted.